# Is Files supporting cbr thumbnails?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

I'm wondering whether pantheon-files supporting cbr/cbz thumbnails, since I don't see this is in the default settings, use special tweaks maybe? The thing is no comic books format thumbnails support is what makes me not using elementary Freya.

Comment: Can you name any OSs that natively support thumbnails for cbr/cbz? It will likely help us find what is missing for this.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 with its nautilus support thumbnails for cbr/cbz.